# Animation on a integer value type in javascript creating an issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 2 functions below- myCalculator() function which holds the variable with static value and animateValue() function will animate that value from **`var start to end`**.(defined var in 1st func.) But the issue is that the value is not animating on form button click

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
     <font class="label">How many people do you want to save per month? </font>  <input placeholder="" id="active-member" type="text" style="width:110px;float: right;"/>
    </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="button" id="contact-submit" onclick="myCalculator();" style="float: right;">Calculate</button>
    </fieldset>

   </form>

  <div class="container2" style="display:none;">
   Animating Value <span id="value" ></span>
   </div>

  <script>
  function myCalculator() {

    $(".container2").show();
    var start = 1000;
    var end = 23600191;
    animateValue("value", start, end, 1000);
    }

    function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
     }, stepTime);
      }

    </script>
```

**Note:**

1. animateValue function is not taking the value of **`var start and end`**
2. 2000 is 2 second
3. myCalculate function calculating some values
4. animateValue function will animating the value

Comment: You have not assigned any value to the `start` and `end` parameters when you call `animateValue`. Worked fine when I added any values to it. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e1xd4ru1/1/

Comment: @Varun scenerio is different here, I need to use start / end variable value from myCalculate() into  animateValue() rather then using static value

Comment: why not call the `animateValue` function from `myCalculate` function itself. Or post some more code to explain what exactly your scenario is.

Comment: @Varun Finally I found the issue, code is working fine but when we change the `var increment`  value from 1 to any number then it will not work. It continuing the animation to infinite number. And Its very important to set the `var increment` value

Comment: this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e1xd4ru1/ check the `var increment` value and try to change it and see..

Comment: I've posted an answer to avoid a long discussion in comments. See if it solves the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163244/discussion-between-jasbir-and-varun-sharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because of the fact that if you have an increment value apart from 1 then if the `increment` does not divide the `range`, you will overshoot the `end` and the loop never stops. So if you have your increment value set to 2, the following won't work

```
animateValue("value", 1, 2000, 2000);
```

Because 2 doesn't divide the `range` ie 1999 in this case but the following will work

```
animateValue("value", 1, 2001, 2000);
```

because the range is 2000 and is divisible by `increment`. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e1xd4ru1/3/

to solve this, you can change your loop exit condition to check whether `current >= end` for positive value of increment and `current <= end` for negative value of increment.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, may be this is the answer, But I am not capable to change the loop exit condition. Can you do it.?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Check the link in the answer

Comment: I have check your fiddle, But can you update your fiddle with main question ?

Comment: @Jasbir have updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e1xd4ru1/4/ . Please do mark as accepted answer if it solved the issue

Comment: Can you seeing my initial asked question.?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle as per the code in the question

Comment: Okk Boss thanks for all support, But ye solve nahi ho paya. You can join my chat if you want.